# XOR gate using simple switches

Tags: switches, logic-gates, light

I want to have two switches controlling my lights room that works like a XOR gate, does anyone know how to do it? I have a very simple switch for testing and I tried many times and couldn't do it as I don't know too much about electronics.

This is the switch I am using:
[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to wire it to another one that looks the same that works like a XOR gate.
I found this diagram online but I don't understand it, here it is though:
[image]
Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this won't work well in the case of your room lights it does show a means of lighting an LED using your switches. This *could* be used to drive an opto-isolator triac, etc., if you really *had* to use those switches.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzDPeK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An XOR configuration to control a small LED load using two SPST switches.*

How it works:

- With both switches open both sides of the bridge rectifier are connected BATT+ by R1 and R2. The LED will not light.
- With both switches low both sides of the bridge rectifier are pulled low. The LED will not light but > 10 mA will flow in each switch for no optical benefit.
- If either SW1 or SW2 is closed current will flow through the LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpNkqX.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. If SW1 is closed current will flow through R2, D3, LED D1, D4 and SW1.*

Answer (score 9):

You need two SPDT (single pole, double throw) switches.  A SPDT switch will have three terminals - your two-terminal switch won't work.

The animated diagram you show is what you want.

**EDIT** (after OP's comment)

This is the required circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fypDZT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If both switches are up, or both are down, the lamp will light.  If the switches are in opposite positions (one up, the other down) the lamp will be off.

A single SPDT switch and a relay won't work, since your original question required two switches.

Comment: Would it work with a relay and a SPDT? instead of 2 SPDT.
And can you show me how to wire it because I don't understand the diagram too well.

Comment: You could use two SPDT relays controlled by two SPST switches. Or one of each, but the contacts at both ends need to be SPDT.

Comment: This is (one form of) the classic two way switching circuit used routinely by electricians. I'd never thought of it as an XOR gate, but of course it is!